# How to indent text inside a PdfPCell

Tags: java, itext

I want to introduce text into a `PdfPCell` and I want part of the text to be indented.
This is what I tried:

```
PdfPCell cell21 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TO:\n\n   name"));
cell21.setColspan(3);
cell21.setFixedHeight(45f);
table.completeRow();
```

The result looks like this:

```
TO:

name:
```

But I expect it to look like this:

```
TO:

   name:
```

In other words: the spaces I've added in front of "name" are lost. How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you could use the [`ALT+0160`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) char for that

Comment: I vote to reopen this question. It is perfectly clear to me what is asked here, but you have to give me some time to answer the question!

Comment: thank you . it will helpful my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of iText are you using? I have tried your code, and it works as expected. Please take a look at the [IndentationInCell](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/IndentationInCell) example:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TO:\n\n   name"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TO:\n\n\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0name"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("TO:"));
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("name");
p.setIndentationLeft(10);
cell.addElement(p);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("TO:"));
p = new Paragraph("name");
p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
cell.addElement(p);
table.addCell(cell);
```

In this example, I create a table with 4 cells, two in text mode (the first two) and two in composite mode (the last two). This results in the file: [indentation_in_cell.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/indentation_in_cell.pdf):

[image]

As you can see, the result is as expected.

In the first cell, we used `"TO:\n\n   name"` just the way you did. The spaces are preserved, although there may have been a bug in previous versions that caused the spaces to be lost.

In the second cell, we used `"TO:\n\n\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0name"` introducing the ALT+0160 character as suggested by @RC in the comments.

In the third cell, we switched to composite mode and we introduced an indentation of 10pt instead of using spaces. Composite mode means that iText no longer looks at the properties of the cell, but instead at the properties of the elements that compose the cell.

In the fourth cell, we change the indentation of the `Paragraph` containing the text. As you can see, it is now outlined to the right.